# Calculating limits for indeterminate forms

Tags: calculus

I am asked to calculate the limit as $x\to0$ of:

$$
\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos(3x)}
$$

I believe this is an "infinity/infinity" problem where i could directly apply L'Hopital's rule. Is this right? how would this limit be found?

Comment: Hint: what is $(e^x+e^{-x})/2$?

Answer (score 1):

The numerator and denominator both approach $0$.  Application of L'Hopital's rule to this problem should be routine, but you'll need to do it **twice**.

Answer (score 0):

1). L'Hopital's rule is a hammer. IMO, it should not be a reflex, definitely not the first thing to try and apply.

2). Do you know Taylor series? *If* you do, recall that
$e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$, $e^{-x} = 1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$, and $\cos 3x = 1- \frac{9x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$. This gives
$$
\frac{1+x+1-x-2 + x^2 + o(x^2)}{1- 1 + \frac{9x^2}{2} + o(x^2) }  = \frac{x^2 + o(x^2)}{\frac{9x^2}{2} + o(x^2) } = \frac{1 + o(1)}{\frac{9}{2} + o(1) } \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} \frac{2}{9}
$$
for your expression.

Comment: Wow, i didn't know taylor series could also be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use L'Hopital's but you have to use it twice. First we see

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{3\sin3x}$$

and then once more (as this is still $0/0$):

$$L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{9\cos3x}=\frac{2}{9}$$

by direct substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{1-\cos3x}=\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^2\cdot\frac1{e^x}\cdot\frac1{\dfrac{1-\cos3x}{x^2}}$$

Now $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1$

and for the last part, use [Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos5x}{1-\cos3x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052738/find-lim-x-to-0-frac1-cos5x1-cos3x/1052754#1052754)